# Validation in namespaces?

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I am wondering what the *best practice* for error validation is using the javascript pattern for namespacing ? Should it be done on a *per page* basis or rather as a *global* one ?

By this I mean:

```
myPage = {
    validation: function() {

    },
    open: function() {

    },
    init: function() {

    }
};
```

or move validation to a higher namespace such as:

```
myValidation = {
    myPage: function() {

    //perform validation

    }
};
```

and return it as `myValidation.myPage()` ?

Comment: I've a bunch of pages [settings, accounts, transfers etc] and wanted to know whether it's better to keep validation grouped on a per page basis - or move it to a higher scope per the code example above?

Comment: Write your code to support its usage, not the other way around.

Comment: sure - but I am wondering what's the *better practice* - to group it per page or to abstract it to a higher scope ?

Comment: Which fits your use case the best? Would one be easier to program than the other? Would it make any difference? I don't think this is really a concern.

Comment: Well, that's what I am wondering. Is it better to simply keep it on a per page basis - allowing another programmer to read the code within the page object - or push all the validation to another object and keep it all together. I'm trying to ascertain what's the best practice ?